# Why does it look like template inheritance only works with nested blocks?

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-templates

Hello I have the following 3 templates (simplified for the purpose of this post):

1 - base.html:

```
//link stylesheet

{% block page_content %}
{% endblock %}

//add bootstrap, jQuery and run scripts
```

2 - base_app.html:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block page_content %}
//html here
{% endblock page_content %}

{% block page_app %}
{% endblock page_app %}
```

3 - base_app_main.html:

```
{% extends "base_app.html"%}

{% block page_app %}

//html i wanna display when I call render(request, 'base_app_main.html', context)

{% endblock page_app %}
```

As it is right now, when I display `3 - base_app_main.html` it does not display the parts inside the `{% block page_app %}`block, however if I change `2 - base_app.html` as below it then works:

2 - MODIFIED base_app.html:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block page_content %}
//html here
{% block page_app %}
{% endblock page_app %}
{% endblock page_content %}
```

And I cannot understand why the template inheritance does not work in the first case and does in the second ?

The documentation or online tutorials I could find do not give relevant multiple inheritance examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So for anyone who gets stuck on the same point, this explanation from an online tutorial made it all clear for me:

> In line 1, {% extends "base.html" %} tells Django template engine that the current template is a child template and inherits from base.html. This must be the first line in the child template otherwise it won’t work. When template engine encounters this line it immediately loads the parent template (i.e base.html) and then replaces the blocks of content in parent template with the blocks of content of the same name defined in the child template.

Basically the template that actually gets rendered in those inheritance schemes is the ancestor or here `base.html`. If you read the below carefully:

> and then replaces the blocks of content in parent template with the
>   blocks of content of the same name defined in the child template

You will see that in the first case when I render `base.html`I will render what is in the `{% block page_content %}` block of it's child which is `base_app.html`. So the webpage I get will not contain anything pertaining to the `{% block page_app %}` block.

The way to fix this is to make the information from `{% block page_app %}` in `base_app_main.html` bubble up to our `base.html`.

To do that I found 2 solutions:

1 - Nesting, or modify `base_app.html` to:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block page_content %}
//html here
{% block page_app %}
{% endblock page_app %}
{% endblock page_content %}
```

In this case when `base.html` is rendered it will take all the information from the `{% block page_content %}` block which now includes the `{% block page_app %}`block and render everything successfully.

2 - Modify `base.html` as such:

```
//link stylesheet

{% block page_content %}
{% endblock page_content %}

{% block page_app %}
{% endblock page_app %}

//add bootstrap, jQuery and run scripts
```

This will explicitly ask `base.html`to render the `{% block page_app %}` block of it's child and also work.

--> Which method is preferred ? I am not sure. The explicit method (2) seems more straightforward, but it also means that if your `base.html` is used across many different projects it will be cluttered with a lot of blocks. Whereas the implicit (1) method is better in terms of DRY... maybe some of you guys can let me know which is "standard".

Answer (score 1):

I think it described pretty clears in the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/templates/language/#template-inheritance) about template inherit

> If you use {% extends %} in a template, it must be the first template
>   tag in that template. Template inheritance won’t work, otherwise.

What you did the first try is basically {% extend %} inside of an {% extend %} in 1 template ,it resulting with the main template which is your base.html have 2 extend tag. And that equal to `Template inheritance won’t work`

Comment: But {% extends % } is the first template tag in all 3 of my templates in both cases...

Comment: when you render your base_app_main you also rendering your base_app and base at the same time so it's consider to be 1 page with 2 extends tag or another word is 1 template

Answer (score 0):

The parent template only takes content from the child within the matching `{% block %}{% endblock %}`.  Your base.html only has a page_content block, so the other block in the child is not included.  You could modify base.html to look like this:

```
//link stylesheet

{% block page_content %}
{% endblock %}

{% block page_app %}
{% endblock page_app %}
//add bootstrap, jQuery and run scripts
```

Comment: I don't understand what you are saying, in this case it is the child block `base_app_main.html` that is supposed to take content from its parent and render it. So I have ` base_app_main.html` extend `{% extends "base_app.html"%}` and it actually displays the code in between the `{% block page_content %}
//html here
{% endblock page_content %}` however it fails to render what is actually defined in it inside the  `{% block page_app %}

//html i wanna display when I call render(request, 'base_app_main.html', context)

{% endblock page_app %}` block...